# Additional page and post status types

Tags: post-status

I have a site where pages will often move from draft to published and then to legacy. I would like to create another status type similar to draft or published titled "legacy". Wherein the page exists but is indicated as no longer active on the site.

Is anyone aware of a Plugin or way to hack this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [**Edit Flow plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/) which  offers a suite of functionality to redefine your editorial workflow within WordPress. Features include **Custom Statuses**

Comment: Glad i cloud help

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [Content Scheduler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-scheduler/) Plugin.

If not that one, then there are [several from which to choose](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/expire).

EDIT:

Since you don't want an automated solution, then I would recommend just training your users to change the Post status to "Private".

Comment: I'm not looking for a timed mechanism to move the post. It would be a manual process. So the employee would hit the drop-down and it would move into the "legacy" section"

Comment: Then why not just make such Posts "Private"?

Comment: I'm not working with geniuses, they need phrasing that is in their native tongue. Directing them to change it to "legacy" is my best option.

Comment: I don't see how that's any easier, either for you or for your users. The meaning of "Private" seems reasonably intuitive.

Comment: I appreciate you opinion Chip, I'll keep it in mind.